# Looking for an introductory book on Differential Equations from a simulation perspective

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, book-recommendation, advice

For work I have to play around and modify existing ecological ODEs written in Python or R.
I am looking for a a textbook that provides some insight on ODEs generally and their dynamics.

Unfortunately most of the textbooks recommended here either focus on how to solve ODEs on paper or on how to implement numerical solvers. I don't envisage either focusing on analytically tractable ODEs (except for testing) nor improving already-made solvers.

What I (think I) need is a book that focuses primarily *using* ODE solvers and simulators for applied work.
Is there anything like it or is it a impossible to get a good grip on ODEs without going through analytical solution-oriented textbooks?

Comment: Have you considered Differential Equations, Dynamical Systems, and an Introduction to Chaos 3rd Edition by Morris W. Hirsch  (Author), Stephen Smale (Author), Robert L. Devaney (Author)? Also, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/201353/recommended-book-on-modeling-differential-equations and https://www.researchgate.net/post/Any_one_can_tell_me_the_best_books_related_to_mathematical_modeling_via_differential_equations

Comment: thanks! For some reason I didn't think about using the keyword "modelling"